# what `?` means before some object attribute? and why my ts file doesn´t accept it?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, conditional-statements

i´ve always use this kind of behavior show down here in angular `*ngIf` directive when i have an object that could be undefined or other than the required object

```
<div *ngIf="object?.foo">
  ...
</div>
```

i know that this works, but don´t know why...

But when i tried to use it on an if in my `TypeScript` file like following angular throw me two diferent errors `TS1005, TS1109`, alternating one to other, on each line that i try to use this behavior.

```
if(object?.foo){} // error TS1109
if(object?.foo){} // error TS1005
if(object?.foo){} // error TS1109
if(object?.foo){} // error TS1005
```

i'm using Angular 7.3.9 for this project

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason it works in your template is because angular will evaluate it to the following expression:

```
<div *ngIf="object && object.foo">
```

Which will prevent the error of calling the property on the object if the object is null.

Documentation link: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths

It is not working in the typescript part of your component because it is not supported by typescript.

The only use of `?` for variables in typescript is to specify that a parameter to a method is optional:

```
function myFunc(mandatoryParam: any, optionalParam?: any) {
    ...
}

myFunc('hello'); // Will work
myFunc('hello', 'world'); // Will work too
```

As mentioned in the comments to this answer, TypeScript will add the support for the angular template syntax in the 3.7 version: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining

Comment: is there some documentation about this behavior in angular html files?

Comment: Yes, I added the link in my answer :)

Comment: You can also use an ! to get around the error. This is more for when you know it won't be undefined at this part of the HTML. For exmaple you would put *ngIf="object!.foo"

Comment: this was a good answer and very helpful thanks , you may include an update about typescript  3.6 Optional Chaining https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining

Comment: @AntoineB, that is not the `only use`, you can also use it to define some optional attributes for an interface.

Answer (score 3):

Typescript 3.7+ has optional chaining (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining)

With that, the expression `if (object?.foo) {}` is valid syntax - the condition will resolve to undefined if `object` is undefined or null.

Check your typescript version.

Comment: I was writing an answer to mention this  